# Why does write memory code running for one process only

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have a python code to write memory process , by pymem lib , but this code is run to one process only , when i open more than one active task process for same exe like , game.exe game.exe game.exe in task manager

this code is run for only first process , why ?

`

```
from pymem.process import *
from pymem import *


mem = Pymem("Game.exe")
game_module = module_from_name(mem.process_handle, "Game.exe").lpBaseOfDll


def getPtrAddr(address, offsets):
    addr = mem.read_int(address)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            addr = mem.read_int(addr + offset)
    addr = addr + offsets[-1]
    return addr


while True:
     mem.write_int(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0xA4G678, [0x4A5]), 4)
     mem.write_int(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0xC4H541, [0x1249]), 1)
     mem.write_int(getPtrAddr(game_module + 0xX3JGBC, [0x2159]), 1)
     break
```

`

i need this code run in all processes for the same exe name

Answer (score 0):

you have a `while True:` expecting the 3 lines to run more than once, right?

That `break` is telling the `while` to never run more than once.

To answer your question; it runs only once because you are breaking the loop at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: I removed Break and same issue

Comment: if you remove `break` you have a new issue; it will run the 3 lines infinitely, forever.  So removing `break` is not the same issue.. You should edit your question, or rather create a new question, to detail the goals and things you have tried and ask SO how to resolve specific problems that you have identified. do not ask why broken code is broken..